# Why are my client threads/listeners not receiving broadcasted messages from the server?

Tags: java, android, client-server, port

I made a simple prototype of a client-server application on Android

I managed to connect two clients to the server and the server can receive their messages. The problem now is that I can't seem to broadcast/receive the messages to other clients.

I try to broadcast the received message through a for loop in the Server class:

```
private void broadcastMessage(String message) {

        for (int i = 0, j = clients.size(); i <= j; i++) {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            Socket socket = clients.get(i);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
            out.println(message);
            Log.d("SERVER Loop", "Broadcasting messages...");
            out.close();
        }
        Log.d("SERVER", "Message Brodcasted");
    }
```

This I then try to receive through a listener in the Client class :

```
    public class ClientThreadListener implements Runnable {

    protected Socket serverSocket = null;
    protected String mMsgFromServer;

    public ClientThreadListener(Socket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    serverSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((mMsgFromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("MESSAGE FROM SERVER: ", mMsgFromServer);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msgFromOtherClients.append('\n'
                                + "Message From Server: " + mMsgFromServer);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientListener", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors or force closes though. Forgive me I know it is very messy but please bear with me and please focus on the issue at hand instead :D

Here is the full code for the Server class

```
public class Server extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;

// DEFAULT IP
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

// DESIGNATE A PORT
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private String mMsgFromClient;

private MultiThreadedServer server;

private ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    // SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    server = new MultiThreadedServer(8080);
    new Thread(server).start();

}

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {

    protected int serverPort = 8080;
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    protected Thread runningThread = null;

    public MultiThreadedServer(int port) {
        this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();
        while (!isStopped()) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                clients.add(clientSocket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isStopped()) {
                    Log.d("SERVER TEXT", "Server Stopped.");
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
            new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, this)).start();

        }
        Log.d("SERVER TEXT", "Server Stopped.");
    }

    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8080", e);
        }
    }

    private void broadcastMessage(String message) {

        for (int i = 0, j = clients.size(); i <= j; i++) {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            Socket socket = clients.get(i);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
            out.println(message);
            Log.d("SERVER Loop", "Broadcasting messages...");
            out.close();
        }
        Log.d("SERVER", "Message Brodcasted");
    }

}

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    protected String mMsgFromClient = null;

    private UUID id;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, MultiThreadedServer server) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((mMsgFromClient = in.readLine()) != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.append('\n'
                                + "Message From Client ID " + getID()
                                + ": " + mMsgFromClient);
                    }
                });
            }
            Log.d("SERVERTEXT", "Proceed to broadcast");
            server.broadcastMessage(mMsgFromClient);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus
                            .append('\n'
                                    + "Message From Client ID "
                                    + getID()
                                    + ": "
                                    + "Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getID() {
        return id.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the full code for the Client class

```
public class Client extends Activity {

private EditText serverIp;
private EditText chatMsg;
private Button connectPhones;
private Button sendMsg;
private TextView msgFromOtherClients;

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;
private boolean willSendMsg = false;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);

    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);

    chatMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_msg);
    sendMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_msg);
    sendMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            willSendMsg = true;
        }
    });

    msgFromOtherClients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_from_other_clients);
}

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);

            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");

            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Server.SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;

            Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientThreadListener(new Socket(serverAddr, Server.SERVERPORT)));
            listener.start();

            while (connected) {
                if (willSendMsg) {
                    willSendMsg = false;
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                        out.println(chatMsg.getText().toString());
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}

public class ClientThreadListener implements Runnable {

    protected Socket serverSocket = null;
    protected String mMsgFromServer;

    public ClientThreadListener(Socket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    serverSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((mMsgFromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("MESSAGE FROM SERVER: ", mMsgFromServer);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msgFromOtherClients.append('\n'
                                + "Message From Server: " + mMsgFromServer);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientListener", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In your server code, do not close the outputstream after writing to the socket. Closing the outputstream will also close the socket.

Comment: I removed it and it still doesn't accept or send the messages. Do you think maybe I also should not close the socket on the Client code?

Comment: In your ClientThread class, you have created two sockets.  You should pass the first socket object to ClientThreadListener instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Call `out.flush()` after each message (both on server and client) to ensure data is send over the socket connection and not buffered.

Comment: What output does your app produce in logcat? And how do you launch your Activities?

Comment: Use PrintWriter.checkError for consistence check on your IO - operations. calls to PrintWriters.println won't throw exceptions, the method is used to validate read / write - operations.

Comment: Place new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, this)).start(); into the try { ... block to avoid threads for clientSocket = null

Comment: should not be necessary, because this statement is reached only if no exception has occured, but makes the code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: calls to close should flush the stream, still flushing it for yourself gives some sort of reliability.

Comment: The client Socket: You instanziating it. Then performing your io - operation. The constructor doesn't connect the socket, though. Sorry, this was wrong, the used constructor does connect the socket.

Comment: Still it may be a good idea to call isConnected.

Comment: Besides: Very well written, specially the synchronized resource handling.

Comment: The mentioned hint about the handling of the call to broadcast itself is perfectly well, you could introduce a local variable and append the value of it to mMsgFromClient before broadcasting, though, if your intention is to only broadcast after full receivment of a message from the client.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some issue that prevents it from working.

- As already said in other answers, in your code you are closing the socket output stream right after sending the message to the client. call `close()` only out of your `for` message loop. Of course closing the socket in the client will have the same effect as closing it on the server. You must close the sockets only when client and server have finished talking. Closing it while transmitting data it's like hanging up the phone in the middle of a conversation.
- Second, you create a new socket on the client side:

  ```
  Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
  Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Server.SERVERPORT);
  ```

  but then you pass to the listener another, newly created, socket (I suppose this is not intended):

  ```
  connected = true;
  Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientThreadListener(new Socket(serverAddr, Server.SERVERPORT)));
  listener.start();
  ```
- Third, always call `flush()` on an output stream right after sending data, or the data will likely not be sent (the send methods will just enqueue your data in the sending buffer).
- Last (This may not be useful to you since I don't know your ultimate goal), if you need to send and receive on sockets, 90% of the time it's better and easier to do this asinchronously, using separate threads for listening and sending.

If it still doesn't work, add here some output or log trace from logcat.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the line:

```
server.broadcastMessage(mMsgFromClient);
```

inside the `while`:

```
        while ((mMsgFromClient = in.readLine()) != null) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.append('\n'
                            + "Message From Client ID " + getID()
                            + ": " + mMsgFromClient);
                }
            });
            // HERE
            Log.d("SERVERTEXT", "Proceed to broadcast");
            server.broadcastMessage(mMsgFromClient);
        }
```

Otherwise, you'll only broadcast `null`.

EDIT: You should make sure that `mMsgFromClient` is not changed between posting the new `Runnable` and it actually executing. The best way is to initialize a field in the anonymous class with the current value, and log the value of that field instead.

EDIT2: Unless your server is supposed to close its connection to a client after sending it a broadcast message, you should use `out.flush()` instead of `out.close()` in the `broadcastMessage` method. It's preferrable that client connections are closed after a timeout, or just let the clients disconnect, again with a timeout.

Otherwise, your test will be very limited most of the times: a client connects and sends a message; then it receives its own message and the server closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use  AsyncTask in android which will create separate thread for communication with server.